# TextField auto width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm displaying some data on a page using `TextField` of `@material-ui` .

The problem is every record of data has different length of data, so most of the values being presented looks ugly (only 10%  of the textfield width is used)

I'm currently using `fullWidth` attribute , but it doesn't do what I want . I want the underline to match the length of the content .

```
<Grid item sm={2}>
    <TextField
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
        inputProps={{ disabled: true }}
        label={labels.brokerId}
        value={props.brokerDetails.id}
    />
</Grid>
```

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Then you have to play with custom css to make underline responsive based on the characters entered

Answer (score 0):

You should try with multiline property of TextArea component.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/text-fields/TextFields.js